# Android - Handle "Enter" in an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I am wondering if there is a way to handle the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> while typing in an `EditText`, something like the onSubmit HTML event.

Also wondering if there is a way to manipulate the virtual keyboard in such a way that the "Done" button is labeled something else (for example "Go") and performs a certain action when clicked (again, like onSubmit).

Comment: Kotlin & Extensions: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48810268/1912924

Answer (score 414, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is a way to
>   handle the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> while
>   typing in an EditText, something like
>   the onSubmit HTML event.

Yes.

> Also wondering if there is a way to
>   manipulate the virtual keyboard in
>   such a way that the "Done" button is
>   labeled something else (for example
>   "Go") and performs a certain action
>   when clicked (again, like onSubmit).

Also yes.

You will want to look at the [`android:imeActionId`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeActionId) and [`android:imeOptions`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions) attributes, plus the [`setOnEditorActionListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setOnEditorActionListener%28android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener%29) method, all on `TextView`.

For changing the text of the "Done" button to a custom string, use:

```
mEditText.setImeActionLabel("Custom text", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
```

Comment: (P.S. EditText extends TextView, thus why the properties you should look at are on TextView - when I first read that last sentence I did a double-take :) )

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why so many things that would seem specific to editing are on `TextView` and not `EditText`. My guess is that either there are other field-like classes in use, or they reserve the right for those sorts of things.

Comment: As a note.  Not all keyboards support the standard android:imeOptions attribute. Which is really dissapointing. For example, IME_ACTION_DONE is defined as 6, where the HTC default keyboard (On phones like Incredible, Evo 4G) the return key is defined as 0.

Comment: Also if your using imeOptions ensure you also use inputType="text" or another equivalent. To ensure the keyboard listens to you! Nexus1

Comment: @CommonsWare i tired changing the IME action label using mEditText.setImeActionLabel("Custom text", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER); and i still just see the icon for the enter button...

Comment: oh it seems that The imeActionLabel sets the label for the button that appears on the top right on full screen IME mode (i.e., when your phone is in landscape).

Comment: setImeActionLabel doesn't always work, any reason why?

Comment: @desgraci: Third-party keyboards don't have to honor it. Beyond that, I have no idea -- you might want to ask a separate question for that.

Comment: @CommonsWare done, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528644/edittext-ignores-the-imeactionlabel, btw no Third-party, standard phones, very simple layout (was just for testing purpose)

Comment: "Yes" - Would you be more descriptive than this? He'll likely ask how to implement the solution.

Comment: @AlWang: First, your area of concern is covered in the answer (see starting with "You will want to..."). Second, this answer is from **six years ago**, and so one would presume that the OP's problem was solved. After all, the OP accepted the answer.

Comment: For some reason when I click `enter` in my edit text, the entire edit text moves down...How can I fix this?

Comment: @CommonsWare For some reason, both OnEditorActionListener() and OnKeyListener() are not working for me. Nothing is happening in onEditorAction() and OnKey() methods

Comment: Tip: Use `actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` for detecting send as well as enter key.

Comment: Thanks, `setOnEditorActionListener()` method helped me.

Comment: Why does this answer get so many upvotes when it provides absolutely no code to show how to actually implement the desired action? Anyone can copy and paste from the Android documentation without actually understanding. This answer is incomplete and not helpful.

Comment: is there any chance to perform click on DONE button ?

Comment: @MilapTank: Just call your own code that would be triggered by the `onEditorActionListener()` listener that you registered.

Answer (score 321):

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          // Perform action on key press
          Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: It would create a problem in case something is copy-pasted in EditText Field

Comment: For some reason when I click `enter` in my edit text, the entire edit text moves down...How can I fix this?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Add android:maxLines="1" to your EditText. Your EditText isn't "moving down", but rather inserting a line break into the text entered. Setting maxLines to 1 prevents the line break from being inserted.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Or you could add this attribute to your EditText `android:singleLine="true"`

Comment: This solution only works for hardware keyboards, NOT for the soft/virtual keyboard.  If you rely on it, then your app will be broken for users without keyboards attached.

Comment: edittext.getText() should be edittext.getText().toString(), correct?

Comment: android:maxLines="1", not android:singleLine="true"  (which is deprecated).

Comment: No offense to CommonsWare, but his RTFM answer was _way_ less useful than this simple example showing exactly how to do it. Thank you!

Comment: @AutonomousApps, I often see CommonsWare answers. He was lucky to answer since 2009, when Android began. Often "yes", "no", "impossible" and so on, usually without code. Often his answers are outdated now, so I try not to follow his recommendations.

Comment: is there any chance to perform click on DONE button ?

Answer (score 221):

Here's what you do. It's also hidden in the Android Developer's sample code 'Bluetooth Chat'. Replace the bold parts that say **"example"** with your own variables and methods.

First, import what you need into the main Activity where you want the return button to do something special:

```
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
```

Now, make a variable of type TextView.OnEditorActionListener for your return key (here I use **exampleListener**);

```
TextView.OnEditorActionListener exampleListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener(){
```

Then you need to tell the listener two things about what to do when the return button is pressed. It needs to know what EditText we're talking about (here I use **exampleView**), and then it needs to know what to do when the Enter key is pressed (here, **example_confirm()**). If this is the last or only EditText in your Activity, it should do the same thing as the onClick method for your Submit (or OK, Confirm, Send, Save, etc) button.

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView exampleView, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
   if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL  
      && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { 
      example_confirm();//match this behavior to your 'Send' (or Confirm) button
   }
   return true;
}
```

Finally, set the listener (most likely in your onCreate method);

```
exampleView.setOnEditorActionListener(exampleListener);
```

Comment: Nice, I've used EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND and I have android:imeOptions="actionSend" on the XML.

Comment: looking for EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND had no effect for me (emulator) so as a foolproof trigger I also looked for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004344/android-edittext-imeoptions-done-track-finish-typing/5369989#5369989

Comment: It's usually better to perform actions on `KeyEvent.ACTION_UP`. In order for this to work, you need to first consume the `ACTION_DOWN` event: `if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { return true; }`. Then you can check for the `ACTION_UP` event and perform the action (similar to the above answer). If you don't consume the `ACTION_DOWN` event, then `onEditorAction` won't be called for `ACTION_UP`.

Comment: This is what worked for me: `if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {...}` -- couldn't get any of the other approaches to work

Answer (score 64):

This page describes exactly how to do this.

https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

Set the [android:imeOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions) then you just check the [actionId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html) in onEditorAction. So if you set imeOptions to 'actionDone' then you would check for 'actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE' in onEditorAction. Also, make sure to set the android:inputType.

If using Material Design put code in TextInputEditText.

Here's the EditText from the example linked above:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend" />
```

You can also set this programmatically using the [setImeOptions(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setImeOptions(int)) function. Here's the OnEditorActionListener from the example linked above:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
            sendMessage();
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i guess this should be the default / accepted answer to this use case (handling enter/submit on a EditText)

Comment: I don't have `OnEditorActionListener`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 44):

Hardware keyboards always yield enter events, but software keyboards return different actionIDs  and nulls in singleLine EditTexts.  This code responds every time the user presses enter in an EditText that this listener has been set to, regardless of EditText or keyboard type.

```
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

listener=new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event==null) {
      if (actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
      // Capture soft enters in a singleLine EditText that is the last EditText.
      else if (actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
      // Capture soft enters in other singleLine EditTexts
      else return false;  // Let system handle all other null KeyEvents
    }
    else if (actionId==EditorInfo.IME_NULL) { 
    // Capture most soft enters in multi-line EditTexts and all hard enters.
    // They supply a zero actionId and a valid KeyEvent rather than
    // a non-zero actionId and a null event like the previous cases.
      if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN); 
      // We capture the event when key is first pressed.
      else  return true;   // We consume the event when the key is released.  
    }
    else  return false; 
    // We let the system handle it when the listener
    // is triggered by something that wasn't an enter.


    // Code from this point on will execute whenever the user
    // presses enter in an attached view, regardless of position, 
    // keyboard, or singleLine status.

    if (view==multiLineEditText)  multiLineEditText.setText("You pressed enter");
    if (view==singleLineEditText)  singleLineEditText.setText("You pressed next");
    if (view==lastSingleLineEditText)  lastSingleLineEditText.setText("You pressed done");
    return true;   // Consume the event
  }
};
```

The default appearance of the enter key in singleLine=false gives a bent arrow enter keypad. When singleLine=true in the last EditText the key says DONE, and on the EditTexts before it it says NEXT. By default, this behavior is consistent across all vanilla, android, and google emulators. The scrollHorizontal attribute doesn't make any difference. The null test is important because the response of phones to soft enters is left to the manufacturer and even in the emulators, the vanilla Level 16 emulators respond to long soft enters in multi-line and scrollHorizontal EditTexts with an actionId of NEXT and a null for the event.

Comment: When I upgraded Java, my Android tool-chain broke. It was 32-bit. I re-installed everything 64-bit and discovered that there are many more public emulator versions available now. I must admit that I only know that the behavior of the EditorActionListener is consistent in the emulators that I tested.

Comment: When I posted this on my blog, someone commented that to make it work on eclipse you need to change the default ime action, adding
android:imeOptions=”actionGo”.

Comment: Oops I misread the comment on my blog post. To make it work on eclipse, you need to change the default ime action, adding android:imeOptions=”actionGo”. **to the ‘EditText’ in the layout xml.**

Comment: On further reflection my last comment refers to both Ant and Eclipse

Answer (score 22):

I know this is a year old, but I just discovered this works perfectly for an EditText.

```
EditText textin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
textin.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

It prevents anything but text and space. I could not tab, "return" ("\n"), or anything.

Comment: Worked for me, with addition of the IME_ACTION_DONE

Comment: Works perfectly fine if you want to disable "Enter" key.

Answer (score 20):

In your xml, add the imeOptions attribute to the editText

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_additem"
    ...
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    />
```

Then, in your Java code, add the OnEditorActionListener to the same EditText

```
mAddItemEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                //do stuff
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here is the explanation-
The imeOptions=actionDone will assign "actionDone" to the EnterKey. The EnterKey in the keyboard will change from "Enter" to "Done". So when Enter Key is pressed, it will trigger this action and thus you will handle it.

Answer (score 18):

Just as an addendum to Chad's response (which worked almost perfectly for me), I found that I needed to add a check on the KeyEvent action type to prevent my code executing twice (once on the key-up and once on the key-down event).

```
if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
{
    // your code here
}
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html for info about repeating action events (holding the enter key) etc.

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar purpose. I wanted to resolve pressing the "Enter" key on the keyboard (which I wanted to customize) in an AutoCompleteTextView which extends TextView. I tried different solutions from above and they seemed to work. BUT I experienced some problems when I switched the input type on my device (Nexus 4 with AOKP ROM) from SwiftKey 3 (where it worked perfectly) to the standard Android keyboard (where instead of handling my code from the listener, a new line was entered after pressing the "Enter" key. It took me a while to handle this problem, but I don't know if it will work under all circumstances no matter which input type you use.

So here's my solution:

Set the input type attribute of the TextView in the xml to "text":

```
android:inputType="text"
```

Customize the label of the "Enter" key on the keyboard:

```
myTextView.setImeActionLabel("Custom text", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
```

Set an OnEditorActionListener to the TextView:

```
myTextView.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
        KeyEvent event)
    {
    boolean handled = false;
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
    {
        // Handle pressing "Enter" key here

        handled = true;
    }
    return handled;
    }
});
```

I hope this can help others to avoid the problems I had, because they almost drove me nuts.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working with the new version 4 of SwiftKey. And it's driving me nuts again... :-/

Comment: your IF is incorrect. use : 'event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER'

Comment: Perfect for me. Also remember to insert the setImeActionLabel again in the IF statement otherwise the custom text disappear after the first press.

Comment: His IF is correct, because he sets his actionId to KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER above :-D, but yes everyone else probably will want to use event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER

Answer (score 10):

You can also do it..

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        && event.getKeyCode() ==       KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) 
                {
                    Log.i("event", "captured");

                    return false;
                } 

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: For some reason when I click `enter` in my edit text, the entire edit text moves down...How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you want to learn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978038/restrict-edittext-to-single-line  othewise show me your xml

Answer (score 7):

If you use DataBinding, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52902266/2914140 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/67933283/2914140.

Bindings.kt:

```
@BindingAdapter("onEditorEnterAction")
fun EditText.onEditorEnterAction(callback: OnActionListener?) {
    if (callback == null) setOnEditorActionListener(null)
    else setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
        val imeAction = when (actionId) {
            EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE,
            EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND,
            EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO -> true
            else -> false
        }

        val keydownEvent = event?.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER 
            && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN

        if (imeAction or keydownEvent) {
            callback.enterPressed()
            return@setOnEditorActionListener true
        }
        return@setOnEditorActionListener false
    }
}

interface OnActionListener {
    fun enterPressed()
}
```

layout.xml:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="YourViewModel" />
</data>    

<EditText
    android:imeOptions="actionDone|actionSend|actionGo"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@={viewModel.message}"
    app:onEditorEnterAction="@{() -> viewModel.send()}" />
```

Answer (score 6):

First, you have to set EditText listen to key press

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    // Set the EditText listens to key press
    EditText edittextproductnumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextproductnumber);
    edittextproductnumber.setOnKeyListener(this);

}
```

Second, define the event upon the key press, for example, event to set TextView's text:

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 // Listen to "Enter" key press
 if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
 {
     TextView textviewmessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewmessage);
     textviewmessage.setText("You hit 'Enter' key");
     return true;
 }

return false;   

}
```

And finally, do not forget to import EditText,TextView,OnKeyListener,KeyEvent at top:

```
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
     password.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(event != null && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
                submit.performClick();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Works very fine for me
In addition hide keyboard

Answer (score 6):

**working perfectly**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
TextView t;
Button b;
EditText e;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e);

    e.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (before == 0 && count == 1 && s.charAt(start) == '\n') {

                b.performClick();
                e.getText().replace(start, start + 1, ""); //remove the <enter>
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b.setText("ok");

        }
    });
}
```

}

**working perfectly**

Answer (score 5):

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId != 0 || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // Action
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Xml

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo|flagNoFullscreen"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1" />
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

           @Override
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

           @Override    
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
             int count, int after) {
           }

           @Override    
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
             int before, int count) {
               if( -1 != input.getText().toString().indexOf( "\n" ) ){
                   input.setText("Enter was pressed!");
                    }
           }
          });
```

Answer (score 4):

Type this code in your editor so that it can import necessary modules.

```
 query.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                // Put your function here ---!

                return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: query = Name of EditText field, and also add this ->(android:imeOptions="actionSearch") in xml of EditText.

Answer (score 4):

you can use this way

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
       if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
          // Do some things      
          return true;
       }
       return false;
});
```

you can see list of action [there](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo).

**For example:**

IME_ACTION_GO

IME_ACTION_SEARCH

IME_ACTION_SEND

Answer (score 3):

This works fine on LG Android phones. It prevents `ENTER` and other special characters to be interpreted as normal character. `Next` or `Done` button appears automatically and `ENTER` works as expected.

```
edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

Comment: This is the ONLY thing that worked for me.  I have a Motorola Moto X 2 and normally it has a "Return" key with the arrow and everything. This changed it to a checkmark and I was finally able to get the listener to work with that. (Before it just created a new line). So if anyone else is having that problem...

Answer (score 2):

InputType on the textfield must be `text` in order for what CommonsWare said to work. Just tried all of this, no inputType before the trial and nothing worked, Enter kept registering as soft enter. After `inputType = text`, everything including the setImeLabel worked.

**Example :** `android:inputType="text"`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple static function that you can throw into your `Utils` or `Keyboards` class that will execute code when the user hits the return key on a hardware or software keyboard. It's a modified version of @earlcasper's excellent answer

```
 /**
 * Return a TextView.OnEditorActionListener that will execute code when an enter is pressed on
 * the keyboard.<br>
 * <code>
 *     myTextView.setOnEditorActionListener(Keyboards.onEnterEditorActionListener(new Runnable()->{
 *         Toast.makeText(context,"Enter Pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 *     }));
 * </code>
 * @param doOnEnter A Runnable for what to do when the user hits enter
 * @return the TextView.OnEditorActionListener
 */
public static TextView.OnEditorActionListener onEnterEditorActionListener(final Runnable doOnEnter){
    return (__, actionId, event) -> {
        if (event==null) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                // Capture soft enters in a singleLine EditText that is the last EditText.
                doOnEnter.run();
                return true;
            } else if (actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                // Capture soft enters in other singleLine EditTexts
                doOnEnter.run();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;  // Let system handle all other null KeyEvents
            }
        } else if (actionId==EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
            // Capture most soft enters in multi-line EditTexts and all hard enters.
            // They supply a zero actionId and a valid KeyEvent rather than
            // a non-zero actionId and a null event like the previous cases.
            if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // We capture the event when key is first pressed.
                return true;
            } else {
                doOnEnter.run();
                return true;   // We consume the event when the key is released.
            }
        } else {
            // We let the system handle it when the listener
            // is triggered by something that wasn't an enter.
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Note that this uses a lambda expression which requires Java 1.8, but its easy enough to convert it to not use a lambda.  However, the problem I've seen with these type of solutions is the virtual keyboard does not auto-hide, and if in fullscreen mode (small device in landscape orientation), fullscreen mode does not turn off after user presses Enter or DONE

Answer (score 2):

```
   final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                // Perform action on key press
                Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Kotlin I've made a function that handles all kinds of "done"-like actions for EditText, including the keyboard, and it's possible to modify it and also handle other keys as you wish, too :

```
private val DEFAULT_ACTIONS_TO_HANDLE_AS_DONE_FOR_EDIT_TEXT = arrayListOf(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND, EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO, EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH, EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)
private val DEFAULT_KEYS_TO_HANDLE_AS_DONE_FOR_EDIT_TEXT = arrayListOf(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_ENTER)

fun EditText.setOnDoneListener(function: () -> Unit, onKeyListener: OnKeyListener? = null, onEditorActionListener: TextView.OnEditorActionListener? = null,
                               actionsToHandle: Collection<Int> = DEFAULT_ACTIONS_TO_HANDLE_AS_DONE_FOR_EDIT_TEXT,
                               keysToHandle: Collection<Int> = DEFAULT_KEYS_TO_HANDLE_AS_DONE_FOR_EDIT_TEXT) {
    setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
        if (onEditorActionListener?.onEditorAction(v, actionId, event) == true)
            return@setOnEditorActionListener true
        if (actionsToHandle.contains(actionId)) {
            function.invoke()
            return@setOnEditorActionListener true
        }
        return@setOnEditorActionListener false
    }
    setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
        if (onKeyListener?.onKey(v, keyCode, event) == true)
            return@setOnKeyListener true
        if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keysToHandle.contains(keyCode)) {
            function.invoke()
            return@setOnKeyListener true
        }
        return@setOnKeyListener false
    }
}
```

So, sample usage:

```
        editText.setOnDoneListener({
            //do something
        })
```

As for changing the label, I think it depends on the keyboard app, and that it usually change only on landscape, as written [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1541161/878126). Anyway, example usage for this:

```
        editText.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
        editText.setImeActionLabel("ASD", editText.imeOptions)
```

Or, if you want in XML:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeActionLabel="ZZZ" android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

And the result (shown in landscape) :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin solution to react to enter press using Lambda expression:

```
        editText.setOnKeyListener { _, keyCode, event ->
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.action==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            //react to enter press here
            }
            true
        }
```

not doing the additional check for the type of event will cause this listener to be called twice when pressed once (once for ACTION_DOWN, once for ACTION_UP)

Answer (score 1):

A dependable way to respond to an <enter> in an EditText is with a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), a [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html), and a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). You need to add the [v4 support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) to use the LocalBroadcastManager. I use the tutorial at [vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html): 7.3 "Local broadcast events with LocalBroadcastManager" because of its complete concise code Example. In onTextChanged **before** is *the index of the end of the change **before the change***>;minus start. When in the TextWatcher the UI thread is busy updating editText's editable, so we send an Intent to wake up the BroadcastReceiver when the UI thread is done updating editText.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.text.Editable;
//in onCreate:
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  public void onTextChanged
  (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    //check if exactly one char was added and it was an <enter>
    if (before==0 && count==1 && s.charAt(start)=='\n') {
    Intent intent=new Intent("enter")
    Integer startInteger=new Integer(start);
    intent.putExtra("Start", startInteger.toString()); // Add data
    mySendBroadcast(intent);
//in the BroadcastReceiver's onReceive:
int start=Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("Start"));
editText.getText().replace(start, start+1,""); //remove the <enter>
//respond to the <enter> here
```

Comment: If using any of the text* input types (e.g. `android:inputType="textCapSentences"`) then carriage-returns are filtered out of the input so onTextChanged() is not called when user presses the Enter key.

Answer (score 1):

This question hasn't been answered yet with Butterknife

**LAYOUT XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/some_input_hint">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textinput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**JAVA APP**

```
@OnEditorAction(R.id.textinput)
boolean onEditorAction(int actionId, KeyEvent key){
    boolean handled = false;
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND || (key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
        //do whatever you want
        handled = true;
    }
    return handled;
}
```

Comment: TextInputLayout and Butterknife: WIN!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a callable function when the user presses the return key.

```
fun EditText.setLineBreakListener(onLineBreak: () -> Unit) {
    val lineBreak = "\n"
    doOnTextChanged { text, _, _, _ ->
        val currentText = text.toString()

        // Check if text contains a line break
        if (currentText.contains(lineBreak)) {

            // Uncommenting the lines below will remove the line break from the string
            // and set the cursor back to the end of the line

            // val cleanedString = currentText.replace(lineBreak, "")
            // setText(cleanedString)
            // setSelection(cleanedString.length)

            onLineBreak()
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Usage**

```
editText.setLineBreakListener {
    doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace "txtid" with your EditText ID.

```
EditText txtinput;
txtinput=findViewById(R.id.txtid)    
txtinput.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))     || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                
                //Code for the action you want to proceed with.

                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                 inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these depencendy, and it should work:

```
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, If none of answers work for you and not get mad yet, I have a solution.
Use AppCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView (yep!) instead of EditText with this code (kotlin)

```
val filter = InputFilter { source, start, end, _, _, _ ->
        var keepOriginal = true
        val sb = StringBuilder(end - start)
        for (i in start until end) {
            val c = source[i]
            if (c != '\n')
                sb.append(c)
            else {
                keepOriginal = false
                //TODO:WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
            }
        }
        if (keepOriginal) null else {
            if (source is Spanned) {
                val sp = SpannableString(sb)
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom(source, start, sb.length, null, sp, 0)
                sp
            } else {
                sb
            }
        }
    }

appCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView.filters = arrayOf(filter);
```

It (probably) work in all device, I test it in android 4.4 & 10. Its work in xiaomi too.
I damn ♥ android :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a helper class for this by extending the new [MaterialAlertDialogBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/dialog/MaterialAlertDialogBuilder)

Usage

```
new InputPopupBuilder(context)
        .setInput(R.string.send, 
                R.string.enter_your_message, 
                text -> sendFeedback(text, activity))
        .setTitle(R.string.contact_us)
        .show();
```

[image: Contact us]

Code

```
public class InputPopupBuilder extends MaterialAlertDialogBuilder {

    private final Context context;
    private final AppCompatEditText input;

    public InputPopupBuilder(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        input = new AppCompatEditText(context);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        setView(input);
    }

    public InputPopupBuilder setInput(int actionLabel, int hint, Callback callback) {
        input.setHint(hint);
        input.setImeActionLabel(context.getString(actionLabel), KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
        input.setOnEditorActionListener((TextView.OnEditorActionListener) (v, actionId, event) -> {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL
                    && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Editable text = input.getText();
                if (text != null) {
                    callback.onClick(text.toString());
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        });

        setPositiveButton(actionLabel, (dialog, which) -> {
            Editable text = input.getText();
            if (text != null) {
                callback.onClick(text.toString());
            }
        });

        return this;
    }

    public InputPopupBuilder setText(String text){
        input.setText(text);
        return this;
    }

    public InputPopupBuilder setInputType(int inputType){
        input.setInputType(inputType);
        return this;
    }

    public interface Callback {
        void onClick(String text);
    }
}
```

Requires

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha04'
```

Answer (score 0):

On Kotlin the Code would be look like the following :

#MVVM #Data-Binding

```html
bidning.messageEditText.setOnKeyListener(object : View.OnKeyListener {
            override fun onKey(v: View?, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    // Perform action on key press
                    if (!bidning.messageEditText.text.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        val text = bidning.messageEditText.text.toString()
                        viewModel.addMyMessage(text)
                        viewModel.requestGptResponse(text)
                        ClearChatBox()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Write Something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way to detect Enter key being pressed is:

```
mPasswordField.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event!= null) {   // KeyEvent: If triggered by an enter key, this is the event; otherwise, this is null.
                    signIn(mEmailField.getText().toString(), mPasswordField.getText().toString());
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```