# Android - customized keyboard key and action

Tags: android, keyboard, customization

If you own Android phone you are no doubt have noticed how in the certain apps the keyboard layout can change from the standard issue to digits-only or to have `.com` or `.net` special buttons based on the text field input type (e.g. phone number). So I have 2 questions:

1. how to trigger this customization? I suspect it has to do with `EditText` format
2. Can this be taken even further if I want to add some custom buttons to inject a specific pattern? Say I would have an `AND` button which when pressed will add all uppercase " AND " surrounded by spaces to the text field. Can this be done?
3. What I'm *not* asking is how to capture some key combination in onKeyPress event and then populate text field with a pattern - I pretty much know how to do that already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is controlled by the `android:inputType` XML attribute (or the `setInputType()` method).

For info on the available options see the pages for the [XML attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) or the [object's method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html).

As an example, the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <EditText 
        android:text="example text"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:inputType="phone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

will give you this layout:

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

whereas changing the `inputType` to `textEmailAddress` will give you this:

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

You can customize the "action" button as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538331/android-cant-figure-how-to-use-setimeactionlabel#1541161), but I don't believe there's any way to do full customization of keyboards at this time, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Do you know if it's possible to fake ALT key on the virtual keyboard somehow? Can I designate say HOME button as ALT?

Comment: No problem... it was something I'd been meaning to play with anyhow :)   I don't think you can simulate the alt key, but again, I could be wrong. It should be noted that it's possible to implement your own keyboard (more or less) from scratch. They have an example:  http://developer.android.com/guide/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html

Comment: Understand. Though implementing full custom keyboard is perhaps a little bit too much for my humble app :)

Answer (score 1):

The thing that concerns me is that "inputType" is listed as a deprecated property, meaning it may work for a while, but - eventually - Android will stop supporting it.  Is there another alternative?

UPDATED: My bad - I'm confusing with inputMethod.