# How can i add the gmail.com after @ if i press the g ? in Email Edittext box

Tags: android, email, android-edittext

I've noticed on other app that the size of the space bar strinks and changes to .com when user select the email field, How can i add the ".com" button on android keyboard.

How can we do the same thing? an we also auto fill gmail.com or homail.com or yahoo.com quickly by detecting the 1st character after @?

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled by [android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType). Try `textUri`.

Comment: i already set but it not displaying me gmail.com if i press g after @ symbol. can u give me some brief introduction for that ?

Comment: see the last example here http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/10/using-edittexts-inputtype-to-control.html to be honest I haven't myself used it. Will see if I can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To autoFill functionality see AutoTextField, or you can listen for edit action by using method

```
textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    });
```

and for KeyBoard feature, see Setting Virtaul KeyBoard Action key,

[Android - cutomized keyboard key and action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670446/android-cutomized-keyboard-key-and-action)