# can i write my own event on android:imeOptions="actionSearch"?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

i am using android:imeOptions="actionSearch"

in editText and my question is can i write my own event if user presses Searchbutton on Softkeyboard?

actualy i want to perform functionality of softkeyboard search button similar to button we use on android activity.

any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I ended up using:

```
EditText SearchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMapSearch);
SearchEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (arg1 == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            // search pressed and perform your functionality.
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Call `setOnEditorActionListener()` on the `EditText` to register a `TextView.OnEditorActionListener` that will be invoked when the user taps the action button on the soft keyboard.

Comment: Look at the BluetoothChat sample that shipped with your SDK, also online at http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html -- or look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538331/android-cant-figure-how-to-use-setimeactionlabel