# Android - Custom IME action button

Tags: android, android-edittext, ime

How can I customize the text displayed in the IME action buttton for an EditTextView. 
I tried to use setImeActionLabel but it doesn't work.

```
public class TestIMEActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final EditText ed1 = new EditText(this);
        ed1.setSingleLine(true);
        ed1.setImeActionLabel("test", 0);
        layout.addView(ed1, params);
        setContentView(layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which label are you trying to change? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1541161/752320) might be of use.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to set it dynamically. Try to set it on your xml:

```
android:imeActionLabel="@string/myCustomActionLabel"
```

It works with me.

Note that your text will be visible only in landscape mode.