# How do I handle ImeOptions' done button click?

Tags: android, android-edittext, ime, on-screen-keyboard

I've got an `EditText` where I am setting the following property so that I can display the "done" button on the keyboard when the user clicks on the EditText:

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

When user clicks the "done" button on the screen keyboard (finished typing) I want to change a `RadioButton` state.

How can I track the "done" button when it is hit from screen keyboard?

[image: Screenshot showing the bottom right 'done' button on the software keyboard]

Comment: may be OnKeyboardActionListener help me any code example??

Answer (score 235):

I ended up with a combination of Roberts and chirags answers:

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_field)).setOnEditorActionListener(
        new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // Identifier of the action. This will be either the identifier you supplied,
        // or EditorInfo.IME_NULL if being called due to the enter key being pressed.
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            onSearchAction(v);
            return true;
        }
        // Return true if you have consumed the action, else false.
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Update:**
The above code would some times activate the callback twice. Instead I've opted for the following code, which I got from the Google chat clients:

```
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    // If triggered by an enter key, this is the event; otherwise, this is null.
    if (event != null) {
        // if shift key is down, then we want to insert the '\n' char in the TextView;
        // otherwise, the default action is to send the message.
        if (!event.isShiftPressed()) {
            if (isPreparedForSending()) {
                confirmSendMessageIfNeeded();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    if (isPreparedForSending()) {
        confirmSendMessageIfNeeded();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I just looked for IME_ACTION_DONE and I was surprised that it didn't trigger. After I also looked for ACTION_DOWN and KEYCODE_ENTER it finally triggered onEditorAction(). Since I see no difference in the built-in keyboard (I expected the Enter key to be highlighted) I wonder what the point is of using android:imeOptions="actionSend" for the EditText XML layout.

Comment: why isn't this answer accepted. does this fail in few cases??

Comment: But this can't work as multiline textView!,In this U can't create the multiline TextView witch using in chat..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html (Description of what an 'event' is affirms same.)

Comment: The second solution is also triggered twice.

Comment: What is `isPreparedForSending()` and why the second method returns `true`?

Comment: @CoolMind It is probably a function to check against invalid strings before sending. IE, is the text in the EditText null / empty. Is it at least 2 characters, etc. Just a guess, but it makes logical sense.

Answer (score 142):

Try this, it should work for what you need:

---

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
       //do here your stuff f
       return true;
    }
    return false;
    } 
});
```

Comment: This does not work for HTC Evo. As far as I've been able to understand, HTC implemented their own soft keyboard which ignores the imeOptions.

Comment: This suffices (no need to look at event action or key code, as in accepted answer); works on my Nexus and Samsung test devices.

Comment: just to be safe, make sure that action in the code and the view matches   ``<EditText android:imeOptions="actionDone" 
    android:inputType="text"/>``

Answer (score 55):

### Kotlin Solution

The base way to handle it in Kotlin is:

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        callback.invoke()
        return@setOnEditorActionListener true
    }
    false
}
```

### Kotlin Extension

Use this to just call `edittext.onDone{/*action*/}` in your main code. Makes your code far more readable and maintainable

```
fun EditText.onDone(callback: () -> Unit) {
    setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            callback.invoke()
            return@setOnEditorActionListener true
        }
        false
    }
}
```

#### Don't forget to add these options to your edittext

```
<EditText ...
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

> If you need **`inputType="textMultiLine"`** support, [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59779604/974045)

Comment: Great answer, thanks for sharing! I seem to keep getting a lint warning regarding the return value of the `setOnEditorActionListener`, though. Maybe it's just a matter of local configuration settings, but my linter really, _really_ wants me to add an `else` branch too in order to accept the "true" as a return statement of the listener (as opposed to the `if`-block).

Comment: You need the ``else`` otherwise it will always return ``false``. A lambda is an expression, the result is always the last value expressed. Even if you go through the ``if`` branch and express ``true``, you immediately move on to the next line and express ``false`` - so that's always your result! Having an ``if-else`` as the last statement means you go down one branch or the other, and it's the last thing you do in the lambda, so you return the result of that branch

Comment: You've an error for the lambda. Instead of `true` you should write `return@setOnEditorActionListener true`, otherwise it will go down to `false` in all cases.

Comment: I'm confused about using return@setOnEditorActionListener true and then returning false without "return@setOnEditorActionListener"

Answer (score 53):

```
<EditText android:imeOptions="actionDone"
          android:inputType="text"/>
```

The Java code is:

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() { 
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Here you can write the code");
            return true;
        }    
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You should return true in the if clause to say you've handled it

Answer (score 27):

I know this question is old, but I want to point out what worked for me.

I tried using the sample code from the [Android Developers website](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html) (shown below), but it didn't work. So I checked the EditorInfo class, and I realized that the IME_ACTION_SEND integer value was specified as `0x00000004`.

Sample code from Android Developers:

```
editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
editTextEmail
        .setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                boolean handled = false;
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
                    /* handle action here */
                    handled = true;
                }
                return handled;
            }
        });
```

So, I added the integer value to my `res/values/integers.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="send">0x00000004</integer>
</resources>
```

Then, I edited my layout file `res/layouts/activity_home.xml` as follows

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:imeActionId="@integer/send"
  android:imeActionLabel="@+string/send_label"
  android:imeOptions="actionSend"
  android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
```

And then, the sample code worked.

Answer (score 18):

More details on how to set the OnKeyListener, and have it listen for the Done button.

First add OnKeyListener to the implements section of your class.  Then add the function defined in the OnKeyListener interface:

```
/*
 * Respond to soft keyboard events, look for the DONE press on the password field.
 */
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
    {
        // Done pressed!  Do something here.
    }
    // Returning false allows other listeners to react to the press.
    return false;
}
```

Given an EditText object:

```
EditText textField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MyEditText);
textField.setOnKeyListener(this);
```

Comment: This doesn't work any more on applications targeting API level 17+, because your OnKeyListener is no longer fired for soft-key events:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html

Comment: Do they suggest an alternative now?

Comment: I've switched to using setOnEditorActionListener to look for EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE, which seems to work well.

Comment: onKey should return true, not false.

Answer (score 17):

While most people have answered the question directly, I wanted to elaborate more on the concept behind it. First, I was drawn to the attention of IME when I created a default Login Activity. It generated some code for me which included the following:

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/password"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
  android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
  android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
  android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
  android:inputType="textPassword"
  android:maxLines="1"
  android:singleLine="true"/>
```

You should already be familiar with the inputType attribute. This just informs Android the type of text expected such as an email address, password or phone number. The full list of possible values can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AinputType).

It was, however, the attribute `imeOptions="actionUnspecified"` that I didn't understand its purpose. Android allows you to interact with the keyboard that pops up from bottom of screen when text is selected using the `InputMethodManager`. On the bottom corner of the keyboard, there is a button, typically it says "Next" or "Done", depending on the current text field. Android allows you to customize this using `android:imeOptions`. You can specify a "Send" button or "Next" button. The full list can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions).

With that, you can then listen for presses on the action button by defining a `TextView.OnEditorActionListener` for the `EditText` element. As in your example:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(EditText v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
       //do here your stuff f
       return true;
    }
    return false;
    } 
});
```

Now in my example I had `android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"` attribute. This is useful when you want to try to login a user when they press the enter key. In your Activity, you can detect this tag and then attempt the login:

```
    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to [chikka.anddev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4835946/2914140) and [Alex Cohn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11331467/2914140) in Kotlin it is:

```
text.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
        event?.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        doSomething()
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

Here I check for `Enter` key, because it returns `EditorInfo.IME_NULL` instead of `IME_ACTION_DONE`.

See also [Android imeOptions="actionDone" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007040/android-imeoptions-actiondone-not-working). Add `android:singleLine="true"` in the `EditText`.

Answer (score 3):

first level :
First, you must specify the following attributes for the action to be able to apply the appearance changes to the keyboard.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLength="11"
        android:lines="1" />
```

second level:

```
phoneNumberET.setOnEditorActionListener(object: OnEditorActionListener {
        override fun onEditorAction(v: TextView?, actionId: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
            if(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE == actionId){
                handleLogin()
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Android Annotations 
https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations

You can use  @EditorAction annotation

```
@EditorAction(R.id.your_component_id)
void onDoneAction(EditText view, int actionId){
    if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
        //Todo: Do your work or call a method
    }
}
```