# Programming "enter" and "shift-enter" for EditText using a soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, keylistener, shift

I am developing an Android application that makes use of EditText (Multiline). The devices I am testing it on lack hard keyboards, so as a result I (obviously) use the soft keyboard. When I touch/click on the EditText the soft keyboard appears. The functionality I intend for the EditText is that when I press "Enter" the soft keyboard dissappears. However, to indicate a paragraph I want to use "Shift-Enter". It's kind of like when typing comments on facebook.

I have been able to imitate the "Enter" functionality with some simple code. By using a KeyEvent and OnKeyListeners. I tried to code it so that "Shift-Enter" would work (e.g. isShiftPressed()). However, after doing some research I found out that "Shift" aparently doesn't trigger a onKey event for soft keyboards.

A lot of the StackOverflow suggestions tell me to use TextChangedListener, but this doesn't work for me because neither shift nor enter actually changes the text in the EditText.

Does anyone know a solution so that I can get the intended function of my EditText? Anything will do at this point I think.

Comment: The code in this answer by Thomas Ahle seems to be exactly what you are searching for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004344/android-edittext-imeoptions-done-track-finish-typing/5369989#5369989 Unfortunately I can't get it to work on my HTC Desire because `isShiftPressed()` is always false.