# How to get EditText, IME Action, textMultiLine, to work for JellyBean

Tags: android, android-widget, android-4.2-jelly-bean, ime

I've run into quite the conundrum and am failing to find a solution. Apparently JellyBean changes how IME actions are handled. I've found many websites offering a solution which indeed works but only for single lined `EditTexts`.  Example: [Stackoverflow: onEditorAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311790/oneditoraction-is-not-called-after-enter-key-has-been-pressed-on-jelly-bean-em)

My `EditText` widgets worked perfectly until JellyBean. It would properly word-wrap until the user hit the "Done" (return) key. Then it'd catch the event with the `OnEditorActionListener` and process accordingly.  I've tried multiple variations of changing the settings with the following XML attributes to no avail:

- singleLined
- scrollHorizontally
- inputType
- imeOptions
- lines

I could only get word-wrapping with no onEditorAction event fired or no word-wrapping with the onEditorAction event firing. How can I get word-wrapping and handle the softkeyboard enter key at the same time for JellyBean?

**Update 1:** Including requested code. Note this is how it stands now which works for all platforms except JellyBean. As I said earlier, tried multiple different XML settings to no avail.

**Update 2:** Managed to get a hold of an Asus Transformer running JellyBean 4.1.1. Works fine. So perhaps this is a device specific bug? My other JellyBean device is a Nexus 7 running 4.1.2. Can anyone verify this with other devices?

Code:

```
private class OnMyEditorActionListener implements OnEditorActionListener {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
            doSomething();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editbox_box_et"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_half"
    android:textSize="24sp" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: It may help to show code and what your build target is.

Comment: Code included. Target is JellyBean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of testing, I've determined this is a bug specific to the Nexus 7 and there is nothing code wise I can do to work around it. Interestingly, if I download a different keyboard from Google Play, then the code actually works!

Comment: On an additional note: Seems like soft-keyboard creators are not forced to support ime option by definition. That would explain why they don't show up on some keyboards. So I guess relying on those as an integral part of the app is not a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

Provide an ID by yourself to your submit/go button

**In activity**:

```
private class OnMyEditorActionListener implements OnEditorActionListener {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == R.id.your_new_ID || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_Null) {
            doSomething();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**In xml**:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editbox_box_et"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_half"
    android:textSize="24sp" 
    android:imeActionId="@+id/your_new_ID"
    android:imeActionLabel="Go"> </EditText>
```

Comment: This was actually quite usefull, solved my problem. I would give you a cookie if i could.

Comment: This seems to work fine. The multiline functionality is preserved and it's now up to me to label and handle the enter key however I want. Lightweight and effective. There are some more fixes related to the same issue in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014219/multiline-edittext-with-done-softinput-action-label-on-2-3

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
android:inputType="text"
android:imeOptions="actionNone"
```

and also check out with different options for word-wrapping in imeOptions xml file

Comment: Negative. Text, actionNone does not work.  I've already tried multiple variations with text, textMultiLine, and textImeMultiLine. Along with actionNone, actionGo, actionDone, and flagNoEnterAction. Nothing seems to work on the Nexus 7

Answer (score 0):

Try adding attribute `android:imeActionId` with integer value (2 for actionGo). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions

Answer (score 0):

I had issue getting the event triggered for Jelly Bean 4.1.2. Adding input type helped me.

```
android:imeOptions="actionGo"
android:inputType="text"
```

Comment: That doesn't allow word-wrapping.