# android: setOnKeyListener issue with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

**UPDATED** `ItemEntryFragment.java` and `ToDoActivity.java` to include my latest attempt to get this thing to work, but it doesn't

I am in an android development class.  our **assignment** is to make a simple todo list using two fragments.  The first fragment is an EditText and the second is a listView.

when a user enters an item into the edittext box and hits enter, the string is added to the listview.

**update 2**  The application now successfully loads on my phone and the fragments look as expected.  however when I press the enter key after inputting text in the EditText line, the setOnKeyListener is never fired.  The code segments are the most current.

any suggestions/pointers would be appreciated.

Below are my xml files that I think are correct

```
main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<fragment
    android:name="com.todo.ToDoListFragment"
    android:id="@+id/todolistFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<fragment
    android:name="com.todo.ItemEntryFragment"
    android:id="@+id/textboxFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

_

```
list_view_fragment.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" > 
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/addItemContentDescription"
    android:hint="@string/addItemHint" />
</LinearLayout>
```

_

```
edit_text_fragment.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

and here are my .java files

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ItemEntryFragment extends Fragment{    

private ToDoListActivity activity;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_entry_box, container, false);    
    final EditText myEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    String newItem = myEditText.getText().toString();
                    activity.addItem(newItem);
                    myEditText.setText("");
                    return true;
                }
            return false;
        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.activity = (ToDoListActivity)activity;
}   
}
```

_

```
public class ToDoListFragment extends ListFragment {
//this class is empty because the ListFragment auto adds the ListView
}
```

and here is my main java file

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class ToDoListActivity extends Activity {

private ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
private ArrayList<String> todoItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //inflate view
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_list);

    //get references to fragments
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    ToDoListFragment todoListFragment = (ToDoListFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.todolistFragment);

    todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    //create array adaptor to bind array to list view
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);

    //bind array adapter to list view
    todoListFragment.setListAdapter(aa);
}   

public void addItem(String newItem){
    todoItems.add(newItem);
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: When you say: "the setOnKeyListener is never fired", have you set a breakpoint at setOnKeyListener and debugged the app?

Comment: yes, it never gets to that breakpoint when I press the enter key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to hook into onEditorAction and set the EditText properties as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311790/oneditoraction-is-not-called-after-enter-key-has-been-pressed-on-jelly-bean-em)

Comment: the work around that the guy in your link used worked for me.  So now when i hit the enter key the string is added from the list.  however the list is on top of the EditText line on the UI.  When i switch the fragments in `main.xml` it will not load the UI