# what is the meaning of "null" KeyEvent

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to assign an EventListener to a editText, but I didn't understand the conditions it used in `EditorAcrion`. obviously the second one is when the user released the key but I'm not sure about the `event == null`. could someone clear this up for me, please.

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
if (event == null || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
  adapter.add(v.getText().toString());
  v.setText("");
}
```

Comment: [In this question someone had a similar issue][1]. Apparently that happens since 3.0.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301061/null-keyevent-and-actionid-0-in-oneditoraction-jelly-bean-nexus-7

Comment: yes I guess that is same problem. it is frustrating when you should memorize these things without any logic behind them. thank you.