# EditText:how to change visibility once the user has done finished typing?

Tags: java, android, xml

How can I change the visibility of an **EditText view** once the user stops typing or clicks done? I tried to do it this but I got an error message.

```
    package com.example.android.monopolycredit;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoginLobby extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_lobby);

        final EditText usernameEditText = findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
        usernameEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(
                new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                                actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                                event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                                        event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                            if (!event.isShiftPressed()) {
                                // the user is done typing.
                                usernameEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return true; // consume.
                            }
                        }
                        return false; // pass on to other listeners.
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm new to android development. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What do you define as finished typing? The `EditText` losing focus or some time passed between the user's last char input or one character entered?

Comment: As soon as the user presses enter. I guess losing focus isn't the best way to do this.

Comment: What is the error message you get ??

Comment: The problem right now is that when I press enter the app just stops working. I'm obviously doing something wrong but I don't get what.

I made the usernameEditText variable final, too.

Comment: you can use `addTextChangedListener` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I change the visibility of an EditText view once the user
>   stops typing...

There is no such event which tells you that user has stopped typing. Even if user stops typing you still have a [focus](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onFocusChanged(boolean,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect)) in that `EditText` field which means that he can proceed typing. Therefore in this case, you can't determine if he really stopped entering text.

> or clicks done?

That's already possible. In order to listen to keyboard changes such as [done](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_ACTION_DONE) action just add `actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE` to your existing code:

```
EditText usernameEditText = findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
usernameEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event){
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE && !event.isShiftPressed()) {
            // the user is done typing.
            usernameEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: When I run this code my application crashes once I click done.

Comment: Can you please share stack trace?

Comment: Probably because I declared 

    usernameEditText

as final, but I end up changing it later on in the code. I don't know how to get around it because I get this error *     
Variable usernameEditText is accessed from within the class, needs to be declared final* when I don't make the usernameEditText variable as final.

Comment: It seems you need to do a nullpointer check: event != null && event.isShiftPressed(). This SO post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301061/null-keyevent-and-actionid-0-in-oneditoraction-jelly-bean-nexus-7

Comment: It's no problem to change the properties of an object, a final variable 'points' to. You just cannot assign a different object to the final variable.