# Key board done button not showing

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to show Done button in key board but this code do not works, please help me solve it. I am new to android.

My Code is:

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:hint="Search jobs"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>
```

Please help me,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this    `android:inputType="text"` And `android:imeActionLabel="Done"`

Comment: android:singleLine="true" add this property in EditText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `android:singleLine = "true"` to your `EditText`

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"
            android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Search jobs"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it in correct way but than also test it in another devices because `imeOptions` do not work on all devices,particularly some older ones.
if you want to do this dynamically than this is the way

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

and to track "Done" button use this code

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(EditText v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
 if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
  //do here your stuff f
  return true;
 }
 return false;
 }
});
```

answer from [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004344/android-edittext-imeoptions-done-track-finish-typing)

for more tutorial [see this link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-and-tracking-done-action-of-android-soft-keyboard-using-ime-options-for-edittext/)

Answer (score 0):

Try  to use   **android:imeActionLabel="Next"**

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:hint="Search jobs"
    android:gravity="center"
android:imeActionLabel="Done"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>
```

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

I have found this issue on older devices. What has worked is to set 
    android:inputType=""

as well as 
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"