# how to add a new key on default android keyboard

Tags: android

I want to add a new key  in the default android keyboard. is there any way to edit android default keyboard and add our new own button on it.
I also want to show it in the setting to make it default keyboard which will popup in the place of existing default keyboard.Is there any way to do  it.Please suggest your solutions ASAP.

Comment: you can replace a button with another using imeOptions  ,., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004344/android-edittext-imeoptions-done-track-finish-typing

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to simply add one key to the keyboard. You might consider implementing your own custom keyboard.

See these options:

[How to make a Android custom keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard)

http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html