# Android EditText imeOptions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, keyboard

I am testing the `imeOption` feature in Android EditText. I understand how it works and the various options like Go, Search, Done etc. My question relates to its event listener.

Take this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369989/682869), for example, the `setOnEditorActionListener` gets invoked when the right corner button on the soft keyboard is clicked.

The `setOnEditorActionListener` will get invoked regardless (if I'm right) of what time option is specified (as long as there is one); then why bother checking what action it was? Won't an Edit text have a fixed time option specified in the xml layout? I don't understand when `setOnEditorActionListener` gets invoked why does everyone check action id ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible reasoning why Android provides action id in the `setOnEditorActionListener` event. I think its because the action associated with an EditText can be changed at runtime. I tried a simple test:

1. Set `imeOptions` to `actionSend`
2. In the event, switched the action to using: `setImeActionLabel("search", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH)`
3. Navigated away from `EditText` and then back to it
4. The soft keyboard now displayed "search" instead of send icon

If anyone has any other reasoning, please share.