# EditText won't accept another input after a wrong answer?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Need to make a loop that handles wrong answers, allowing another input to `EditText`

```
mEdit.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
   public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

         if(sumAsString.equals(mEdit.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "That's right!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } else {
             mEdit.setText(null);
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry Try again ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Try with remove this line `return true;`

Comment: I suggest you use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) instead of KeyListener.

Comment: Is `mEdit.setText(null);` this line okay to use?

Comment: Didn't work. No input will show up after a wrong answer.

Comment: use  this `mEdit.setText("");` instead of `mEdit.setText(null);`

Comment: mEdit.setEnabled(false);    and  mEdit.setText("");/mEdit.setText(null);

Comment: Please, add more description about what you are trying and what going wrong.

Comment: Why not using TextWatcher?

Comment: try `IMEAction` instead of  `KeyListener`

Comment: doesn't it need to be a loop until the correct answer is entered?

Comment: android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"    Whew.....that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IME_ACTION` instead of key listener like below

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

And use `OnEditorActionListener` on `EditText` like below

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(EditText v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
           //do here your stuff f
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    } 
});
```

**Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004344/how-do-i-handle-imeoptions-done-button-click).**

It'll help you.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing `return false;` or put it above the parenthesis.

```
mEdit.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
   public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                            if(sumAsString.equals(mEdit.getText().toString())) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "That's right!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                mEdit.setText(null);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry Try again ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                return true;

                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
```