# How i can link the button listener with the enter in the keyboard in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want when the user click "Enter" on the keyboard the actions happening in pressing a Button happens

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004344/how-do-i-handle-imeoptions-done-button-click

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.