# On Edit Text to another on the pressing Enter?

Tags: android, android-edittext

i jave two editText boxes in my app, after having entered value in the first one i would like to move to next editText box on pressing Enter? This is what i have tried so far...

```
editText1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if((event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
        {
            editText1.clearFocus();
            editText2.requestFocus();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `android:singleLine="true"` line added to you `EditText` in the layout XML? Or alternately you can set it by using [setSingleLine()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSingleLine%28%29) in code. This forces the edit text to use only one line and focus will go to the next EditText box when you'll press Enter. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6420336/1306419) by @Scott on [Handle enter key in EditText across different devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401887/handle-enter-key-in-edittext-across-different-devices) .

Comment: @PrasadAinapure Glad it helped you. Please accept one of the answers or give your own answer and accept it. This will mark the question solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use many IME options in EditText XML Layout, and request focus on it. Example:

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText_Search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_search_box"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter information"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:saveEnabled="true"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    <requestFocus />
```

The key to this is `android:imeOptions` set to "next". You could set the final editText in your `View` to `android:imeOptions="done"` and do something with that, maybe a Login or the like. And finally the end-tag `<requestFocus />`

I hope this helps, happy Coding!