# must press enter key twice to do the work

Tags: android

I have a problem with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in android, I have an edittext where I enter a value and then when I click on <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I want it to make something. My problem is that I have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice to get the desired results.

```
    editText1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

              // Perform action on key press
              mWebView.loadUrl(editText1.getText().toString());
              mWebView.requestFocus(); 
              return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue once before. Have you tested this on an actual phone, or are you just trying this in the emulator. I can not remember the specifics of my original experience, but I found that it was due to lag in the emulator. Try signing the app and sideloading it onto a phone to see if the desired effect happens. However, if that doesn't resolve it for you, check out this other post:

[Android - Handle "Enter" in an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext)