# Handle "press enter key" on android

Tags: java, android

I created a little app that has a search bar. now I want to know if I can handle the situation when a user press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. so the app can call the `buttonOnClickListener()` that actually perform the search?

Answer (score 1):

for handling you Search button on keyboard, you can refer here.

[Android - Handle “Enter” in an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1489852/593709)

and for performing the same action as `buttonOnClickListener(View)` do something like this:

```
yourSearchButton.performClick();
```