# Accesing softkeyboard buttons with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, dojo, keyboard

i have developped a mobile app with dojo and phonegap for android. The problem is, that I want to acces the bottom right corner button. I want to change its name to "send" and I want to connect the button with a function. Does anyone have an idea how to do that? Using javascript, or how to do that natively?

Comment: This should help: 
http://www.practicaldeveloper.net/2011/09/creating-plugin-with-phonegap-10.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively it is possible to change the text to certain other limited options however I doubt whether it is possible to do from the context of a PhoneGap app.

Check this post which details the process of doing relatively same but in native.

[Android - Handle "Enter" in an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext)

For more detail you need to check the [doc](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html)