# Recommendations on the use of an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need a way to take text from a "EditText" as soon as the user presses "Enter" and it should also call a method if it loses focus.

I created EditText like this:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:ems="10" >
```

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext) is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive key presses your EditText needs to have focus:

```
editText1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText1.requestFocus();
```

then set the onkeylistener():

```
editText1.setonKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(

@override onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
// what you need to do when Enter is pressed
return true;

}else return false;

}
```

For focus lost, you need to implement the `View.onFocusChange` interface and check that `hasFocus` is `false`

Comment: Check this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Use an EditText action listener. Refer to this question, it's probably the same: [Handle Enter in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext)

For detecting loss in focus:

```
if(!(et.isFocused)){
  //call your method here
}
```

Comment: Hello, I can have a method that handles the event?