# why is the EditText multi-line in android

Tags: android

I'm surprised that why EditText is multi-line in android i-e when we hit return key it goes to new line, and I also want to ask that can we add an event listener on pressing return key while working in EditText and not to go on new line. please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`android:SingleLine`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine)**

```
<EditText
    android:singleLine="true"
    ...
    ...
```

To detect an Enter key-press
`edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() { ... });` can be used. (**[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html)**)

Also, see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext) for more.

Comment: Dear! I want that EditText must be single line not multi line and Q is `Why EditText is multi-line`

Comment: @ArshadAliSoomro I mean't I did not read your question correctly at first. I thought you needed it to be multi-line. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        for (int i = s.length(); i > 0; i--) {
            if (s.subSequence(i - 1, i).toString().equals("\n"))
                s.replace(i - 1, i, "");
        }
    }
});
```