# Parse EditText after the user hit Enter

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a pretty easy problem to solve but I can't see any tutorials on internet to help me. Because this problem is pretty basic I think I don't use the right keywords for my search.

My problem is that I parse an `EditText` with a method and use this method to feed the values of a graph:

```
public int getSetPoint(){
    int setPointRequest = Integer.parseInt(txtSetPoint.getText().toString());
    if (setPointRequest > 90 && setPointRequest < 120);
        return setPointRequest;
    // ...
}
```

I would like to parse the value only if `setPointRequest()` has the values between `91` and `119` and after the user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keypad. When the user is prompted to enter a value only numbers are shown on the keypad already.

Currently all the values that the user inputs even if he doesn't hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> are registered on the graph.

Thanks for your help!
Math

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int getSetPoint(){
  int setPointRequest = Integer.parseInt(txtSetPoint.getText().toString());
  if(setPointRequest>90 && setPointRequest<120) //notice the lack of ;
    return setPointRequest;

  return -1;
}
```

To handle an enter key:

```
txtSetPoint.setOnEditorActionListener ( new OnEditorActionListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
  {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL)
      getSetPoint();
    return true;
  }
});
```

Your first issue is the semicolon right after the `if`. Remove that.

Second issue is that after you fix this issue, you will get a compile time error since you need a default return statement (that can be guaranteed to execute in case your if doesn't). I used `-1`, you can customize it to your needs. I'd also put the parsing in a `try/catch` just to be safe from any odd errors, but it's up to you.

In addition, the naming is bad, `getSetPoint()` is not immediately clear from the name, but the return type and lack of arguments do give a rough idea.

Comment: This solution crash my application and does not help me with the "enter" on the keypad I asked. Could you please elaborate this solution ?

Comment: @Mathieu660 then post how you're calling this method. It is most likely crashing since `-1` (the default value) is returned, and you're not revalidating your input. As for handling enter keypresses, you will want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext) answer. However, you should make a button instead, it is more clear *and* it allows you to easily handle the submit.

Comment: actually I inputed another value because -1 will of course crash my graph. I used 98 but still it crash my app. setPointValue.add(getSetPoint()); it's called there and it's an array

Comment: @Mathieu660 Would you like to edit your question to post more code and a stack trace? All I changed with your method was taking out the semicolon and then adding a default return, which is needed to compile. Something else seems amiss.

Comment: Will do that for the "enter" part but I fixed the return problem there was something else I was doing that was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Combining what A--C said, Us the setOnKeyListener for your EditText so that it will only get the text when the user hits the enter key.

```
public int getSetPoint(){
  int setPointRequest = Integer.parseInt(txtSetPoint.getText().toString());
  if(setPointRequest>90 && setPointRequest<120)
    {return setPointRequest;}

  else {return -1;}
}

txtSetPoint.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){ //this method waits for the enter key to be hit

@Override
public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {

    switch(arg1)
    {
          case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
               getSetPoint(); //when enter key is hit, call the getSetPoint method
               return true;
          default: 
               return false;

    }

   }
});
```