# android edittext to replace br.readLine()

Tags: android, android-edittext, chat

I'm trying to alter some sample code I found. It's a one on one chat application but all commands are delivered and read by a buffered reader's `br.readLine();`. I need to alter that and instead of (within a while loop) wait for the user to input text in the console (via br.readLine();), but rather to wait for the enter key on an edit text to be entered.

My code sample that I have so far is :

```
    String command;
    while(true) {
        try {
            command=br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error reading command");
            if(pendingChatAccept) {
                sendThroughSocket(Constants.Client.CHAT_DENY, clientSocket, pendingAcceptClient.getIP(), pendingAcceptClient.getPort());    //deny the request
                pendingChatAccept=false;
                pendingAcceptClient=null;
            }
            continue;
        }

        if(pendingChatAccept) {
            char c=command.charAt(0);
            if(c=='y') 
            {
                System.out.println("\nRequest Accepted. Type 'm' to send a message.");
                sendThroughSocket(Constants.Client.CHAT_ACCEPT, clientSocket, pendingAcceptClient.getIP(), pendingAcceptClient.getPort());  //accept the request
                currentChatPartner=pendingAcceptClient;
                currentlyChatting=true;
                pendingChatAccept=false;
                pendingAcceptClient=null;
                msgQueue.clear();   //clear message queue
            } else {
                System.out.println("\nRequest Denied.");
                sendThroughSocket(Constants.Client.CHAT_DENY, clientSocket, pendingAcceptClient.getIP(), pendingAcceptClient.getPort());    //deny the request
                pendingChatAccept=false;
                pendingAcceptClient=null;
            }
```

So instead of waiting at `command=br.readLine();`, I'd like to wait till a command has been read from the edittext. Is there a way to do this??

I've been struggling for two days now and just can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: you question is unclear...

Comment: My question is: Can I, instead of waiting for command=br.readLine(); to be entered in the system console, wait for an enter key to be pressed and assign the text in the edittext to the command string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 EditText et=new EditText(getApplicationContext());


    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

you can use a **KeyListener** like that:

```
 final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
              // Perform action on key press
              Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

i copy the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext)

Comment: And by putting this in the while loop, it will only exit the while loop (as is in my code) when the enter key is pressed?

Comment: use a boolean parameter to exit the loop (change it from true to false in this method), and while(YOUR_BOOLEAN)

Comment: Was thinking something along those lines, but wasn't too sure. Will check it out and let you know and mark as answer when I've attempted it. Thank you for such a quick and helpful response!