# edit_text.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() return error

Tags: android, eclipse

I m trying to add a key listener to my EditText. But eclipse return an error. The eclipse does not recognize `setOnKeyListener` and  `KeyEvent`

Here after my code

```
        edit_text.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
        {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    switch (keyCode)
                    {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                            // YOUR CODE
                            return true;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

The error message is:

```
The method setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnKeyListener(){})
```

How I can fix that?

Comment: just use `setOnClickListener()` at the place of setOnKeyListener

Comment: plese post the `logcat` error so we can identify the bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to catch enter click from soft keyboard i suggest use "OnEditorActionListener".
you cant see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4889059/1928342) answer to solve it.

if you want to use "OnKeyListener" in the same link scroll down and you will see another answer for that.
(if your imports do the problem just add them manually).

Answer (score 0):

> To identify enter event

```
txt.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
    {
              outview.setText(editor.getText());
    }
    return true;
}
});
```