# Android can EditText make next focus to any view?

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, focus

Normally, if I have many EditText in LinearLayout, when I pressed Enter in one of the EditText, it will automatically jump to next EditText.

My question is can I pressed Enter in a EditText and make it jump to other view(like ImageView,Checkbox...)?

Answer (score 0):

Add onEditorListener to the EditText and catch the Enter press then you could do whatever you want. [read it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext)