# EditText unable to backspace or enter

Tags: java, android

I have a edittext on my view.  For some reason I am not able to backspace or enter.

I am able to type, but i can not backspace.   Here is my xml code

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/command"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spower"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sp_test"/>
```

All i have in my java code about the edittext is a if/else statement.

So i can't figure out why i can't hit enter or delete?

Comment: Reference  this post : Android Handle Enter in an EditText http://stackoverflow.com/a/1489895/3155563

Comment: you can't press enter because you have _android:imeOptions="actionGo"_, which has replaced enter button with "Go" button. Now the backspace is not logic..