# how to activate a button when the user hits enter on a specific edittext

Tags: android

how do i activate btn_aprove when the user hits enter/next/ready from shelfnumberbox when the user has text in it

```
shelfnumberbox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                btn_aprove.performClick();
            }
        });
```

Comment: duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
shelfnumberbox.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            btn_aprove.performClick();
        }
    return false;
    }
});
```