# Android WebView Capture Keyboard Enter and Close Keyboard

Tags: android, webview, user-input, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events

I have a WebView in my Android app. The WebView has a basic number input in it. Currently when you hit enter, the keyboard stays open and the calculations take place.

But the calculations get displayed beneath the input and are hidden behind the keyboard.

As such, I want to hide the keyboard once enter is hit.

While I see [ways to hide the keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-can-i-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard-programmaticallyhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-can-i-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard-programmatically) and [ways to capture keys from Android EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39370352/how-to-catch-soft-keyboard-enter), I don't see a way to capture keys from a WebView input.

How can I capture a WebView input's keyboard events (specifically enter) and then close the keyboard?

Comment: It may be useful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66922725/5595926