# Android unable to capture Enter Key on EditText

Tags: android

I have been trying to capture the Enter key for the past couple of hours but I donot get a call in the Listener. I am trying to provide a "Press Enter to send". But am always registering for the OnKeyListener. A few keys get called but randomly.

Its not a duplicate, since all the answers provide the same set of details, and this is a standard code. I am using the nexus 6P

My Code:

```
public void onCreate(){
        //set press enter to save state
        anEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
               if( keyCode ==
                        EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                   if (new SharedPrefsManager(mContext).getBoolean(StringConstants.KEY_PRESS_ENTER_TO_SAVE, false)) {
                       Toast.makeText(mContext, "Enter pressed, to save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                   return true;
               }
                return false;
            }
        });
}

@OnCheckedChanged(R.id.check_enter_to_send)
public void enterToSendChecBoxClicked(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
    // 1. set the preference
    new SharedPrefsManager(mContext).putBoolean(StringConstants.KEY_PRESS_ENTER_TO_SAVE, isChecked);
}
```

Comment: Try parenthesis around `IME_ACTION_SEND` and `KEYCODE_ENTER` conditional

Comment: @cricket_007 Well my onKey() itself does not get called, so the problem is not in the logic.

Comment: Seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4889059/2308683

Comment: Yes but did not try the onEditor Action onKey felt like the simplest way

Comment: The onEditorAction does not work either.

Comment: Please [edit] with that attempt as well. And [read the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext/4889059#comment25693751_4889059)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no API for handling keyboard events on soft keyboard, only for hardware keyboard.

according to [Handling Keyboard Actions](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html):

> Note: When handling keyboard events with the KeyEvent class and related APIs, you should expect that such keyboard events come only from a hardware keyboard. You should never rely on receiving key events for any key on a soft input method (an on-screen keyboard).

Comment: @AkshatArora TextWatcher listens for alterations of the length of the string that is typed, not the key-presses that build the string.

Comment: I know and I can check for the delta to see if the last key was a "\n"

Comment: @AkshatArora, yes, you can try this way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37579329/2715054

Comment: I implemented a TextWatcher to implement this feature. Thanks @phnmnn for pointing me in that direction.