# How to customize the 'Enter' of the virtual keyboard when giving input in an Android app and also handle its click action?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext, user-experience

I am searching for a way to customize (or handle) the 'Enter' of the virtual keyboard when some app user is giving some input in an Android app, for example, when he is pressing "*Enter*" in an Android app (in some EditText) or when he has completed giving his input, then at that point (or before) can I customize the 'Enter' of the virtual keyboard (like in some apps' virtual keyboard, it is "*Done*") to text like "*Go*" etc. Also, if something like some (other) action could also be possibly performed when that virtual keyboard button (like Enter) is being clicked or pressed. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1489895/6404749

Answer (score 1):

You can set different imeOptions like actionDone and actionGo reference [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:imeOptions)

imeOptions can setted like this in editText

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

to customize these imeActions firstly you can change imeOptions label like this

```
android:imeActionLabel="@string/anyString"
```

You have to implements OnEditorActionListener interface and set it to your EditText

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your changes have been saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> set ImeOptions

```
et_input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

> Editor Action Listener

```
    et_input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            int result = actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION;

            switch (result) {
                case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:

                    break;
                case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
                    //
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```