# How to automatically press enter key when edittext is not null?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, keypress

I'm make a EditText and the value i got from Firebase, it is possible if edittext is not null then enter key pressed automatically

```
private void init(){
    Log.d(TAG, "init: initializing");

    if (mSearchText != null){
       what must i write here?
    }

    mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                    || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                //execute our method for searching
                geoLocate();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1]  you can try below code

```
String yourtext=mSearchText.getText().toString().trim();
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(yourtext)) //or else you can use  if(yourtext!=null && !yourtext.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{
    mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                    || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                //execute your method for searching
                geoLocate();
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

[2] else you can achieve your functionality using this(Direct method calling)

```
String yourtext=mSearchText.getText().toString().trim();
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(yourtext)) //or else you can use  if(yourtext!=null && !yourtext.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
{
     //execute your method for searching
                geoLocate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
EditText editText;
BaseInputConnection inputConnection = new BaseInputConnection(editText, true);
inputConnection.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POUND));
```

[read more](https://www.pocketmagic.net/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/)